# How to call PHP a class from parent namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

I have the following namespace structure with the following class files

```
Application
|->App.php
|->Top
   |->Start.php
   |->Process.php
   |->Child
      |->Plugin.php
```

So in App.php I've declared

```
namespace Application;
```

in Startp.php declared

```
namespace Application\Top;
```

in Plugin.php declared

```
namespace Application\Top\Child;
```

I see that I can call the Plugin.php class from the App.php like

```
$object = new Top\Child\Plugin();
```

if it's a child/grandchild namespace, but what if I want to call Process.php from Plugin.php, which is the parent namespace from the branch? Is there something like double dots ".." to indicate the upper parent directory in namespace? I am trying to call something like

```
File: Plugin.php

$object = new ..\Process();
```

it didn't work, it looks like I can only start all the way from the root like

```
$object = new \Application\Top\Process()
```

Is this the only option? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried "usings": `use Application\Top;` and then call `$object = new Child\Process();`

Comment: @Saul Thank you for the answer, but I already know that, I am trying to find out if there is an shorter way to call a class that resides right above the parent level from a child level

Comment: I see. I've never thought that, haha. I'm used to put my "usings" at the top, even a namespace above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As it mentioned here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php (in comments) there is only one way to specify namespaces - from root. You can not use ..\ to shorten namespace calls. To shorten calls in you code you can use

```
use \Application\Top\Process as SomeProcess;
```

and use, first at your code

```
$object = new SomeProcess();
```

Also you can write your class loader. To call $object = new ..\Process(); Here is the sketch:

```
$classPath = explode("\\", __NAMESPACE__);
array_pop($classPath);
$newClassPath = implode("\\", $classPath) . '\\'. 'Process';
$object = new $newClassPath();
```

Be sure to use double backslash when you want to use them in single quotes.

Comment: Thank you, actually I have read all those, it's just amazes me that namespace isn't flexible as I thought, so just to confirm if I haven't missing something.